# Is this sparsity constrained convex projection problem NP-hard?

Tags: complexity-theory, computational-geometry, np-hard

Suppose we are working in ${\mathbb R}^d$ (dimension is not fixed), and we have a set of $n$ points $X = \{x_1,\ldots,x_n\}$ in that space. Given a query point $y$ inside the convex hull of $X$ and an integer $m$ where $m<d+1$, we want to choose $m$ out of the $n$ points so that the residual of the projection of $y$ onto the convex hull of the $m$ points is minimized, out of all $n \choose m$ ways to choose $m$ points. If $d,n,m$ are part of the input, is this problem NP-hard?

Definition: The residual of a projection from $y$ to $x$ is the Euclidean distance between two points $x$ and $y$, namely, $\sqrt{ \sum_{j=1}^d (x_j - y_j)^2}$.   The residual of a projection from $y$ to a convex hull $H$ is the minimum of the residual of the project from $y$ to $h$, where $h$ ranges over all points on the perimeter of the convex hull.